# Как сделать такой hover

Tags: css, css3

Привет, народ. Как сделать что-бы при наведении курсора на картинку,
появлялась рамка по углам?
В голову лезу совсем дикие идеи с 4 маленькими квадратными блоками...
и то не понимаю до конца как реализовать.

[image: хитрый угловой border]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```css
.block {
  position: relative;
  padding: 5px;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #fff;
}

.block:hover {
  background-color: #B7E522;
}

.block:before {
  content: "";
  width: 90%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 5%;
  background-color: #fff;
}

.block:after {
  content: "";
  width: 100%;
  height: 90%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 5%;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #fff;
}

.block>img {
  position: relative;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  z-index: 999;
}
```

```html
<div class="block">
  <img src="https://t4.ftcdn.net/jpg/01/85/66/43/500_F_185664319_kxK75qclPnH3trVYEf7wnid2VUmYaHYB.jpg">
</div>
```

Comment: Хорошее решение!

Answer (score 2):

В общем сначала создаём общего родителя для углов и для img , в моём случае это .caption внутри него лежат наши эмитированные углы .. их для стилизации объединил по общему селектору т.е .border и скрыл их через opacity а по hover делаю полную не прозрачность

```css
.caption.x1{
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  width:60%;
  margin:20px auto;
  position: relative;
}
.caption.x2{
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  width:70%;
  margin:20px auto;
  position: relative;
}
.caption img{
  display:block;
  width:100%;
}
.tbil{
  border-left:5px solid red;
  border-top:5px solid red;
  position: absolute;
  top:-5px; left:-5px;
}
.tbir{
  border-right:5px solid red;
  border-top:5px solid red;
  position: absolute;
  top:-5px; right:-5px;
}

.bbil{
  border-left:5px solid red;
  border-bottom:5px solid red;
  position: absolute;
  bottom:-5px; left:-5px;
}
.bbir{
  border-right:5px solid red;
  border-bottom:5px solid red;
  position: absolute;
  bottom:-5px; right:-5px;
}
.border{
  width:20%;
  height:30%;
  opacity:0;
  transition:all .4s linear;
}
.caption:hover .border{
  opacity:1;
}
```

```html
<div class="caption x1">
  <div class="tbil border"></div>
  <div class="tbir border"></div>
  <img src="http://fb.ru/misc/i/gallery/14907/269817.jpg" alt="">
  <div class="bbil border"></div>
  <div class="bbir border"></div>
</div>

<div class="caption x2">
  <div class="tbil border"></div>
  <div class="tbir border"></div>
  <img src="http://kino-kingdom.com/uploads/posts/2017-10/1507789838_maxresdefault.jpg" alt="">
  <div class="bbil border"></div>
  <div class="bbir border"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: На примере автора рамка за пределами картинки, так что наверное изменить позиционирование на `top:-5px;left:-5px;` (топлево)

Comment: @Telion  исправил

Answer (score 0):

```css
.main img {
  border: 3px solid transparent;
}

.main img:hover {
  border: 3px solid #40c4c8;
  border-image: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/QBuDC.png) 3;
}
```

```html
<div class="main" id="maincontent">
  <img alt="stegosaurus" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/tCMsF.jpg">
</div>
```

Comment: "Мы не выбираем лёгких путей!" =)

Comment: :-). Через тернии, к звёздам! Идём. Тернии, тернии, когда же звёзды?

Comment: Вы про точки на небе?=)